# Jquery file changed to new version

Tags: jquery

I have changed jQuery-core-1.2.1.min.js file with latest version jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js leads few of the functionalities not working in Iframes tree concept. Should I maintain two files in my application to support the existing functionality.

Comment: what is the question ? issue ? objective ? Just use your 2 old files for page with your iframes tree concept...

Comment: @darkomen, recently in application changed jQuery-core-1.2.1.min.js file with jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js in all pages, there is an issue in one page where frames are used in one of the frame jQuery-core-1.2.1.min.js is using, replace this with latest jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js functionality not working, my doubt : is there any functionality that supports by old version not supported by new version, Should we maintain both version files to resolve this type of issues.

Comment: You can try the jquery migrate plugin. It's in the official download page

Comment: @Enrico, Hi I did not get your point

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Comment: @Enrico, can we keep both version files in application....

Comment: You can have different jQuery version on **different pages** or.. you can use the jQuery migrate plugin and keep only the newer version.